Intersection of smooth manifolds - can tangent manifolds also be a manifold?
Referring to this question asked some time ago:
Intersection of smooth manifolds
I have a follow-up question (which I'm not able to add to the existing question - hence this new question):
I have read in several places that transversality always fails whenever two submanifolds are tangent, and also that a tangent submanifold itself is not typically considered a manifold because it only captures the "infinitesimal" direction at a point on a manifold, not a full geometric structure that extends across a neighborhood.
Isn't what the accepted answer to the question describes a "tangent manifold" - or am I mixing things up here?
Can, say, two 3-d (or two 2-d) submanifolds that are tangent be considered a manifold?

@EricTowers I don't understand how your comment answers my question. Where else can they be tangent if not at their intersection? If they don't intersect, they can't be tangent can they?  So the question is, if two submanifolds touch at a single point (doesn't that mean they are tangent?), is the result a manifold (that is comprised of the original two, now touching, submanifolds)?

The accepted answer to the cited question gives a single point intersection of two manifolds.  This is not a tangent manifold except for the one point manifold.  The easiest way to see that an intersection of manifolds is by following units (the way physicists do).  The manifolds live in $\Bbb{R}^2$ having, for example, units of $\mathrm{meter} \times \mathrm{meter}$.  That is $(2,3)$ represents the point $2$ meters to the right of the origin and $3$ meters above it.  The tangent space at a point is the space of velocities at that point, which have different units...

What is a tangent manifold? I know what a tangent bundle is, but in my 50 years doing mathematics, I've never hard of a tangent manifold. Please edit your post to include more information.

Is $y^2=x^4$ a submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$? Is it a manifold?

@TedShifrin I thought, but maybe I was hallucinating, that I had seen a definition somewhere that suggested that two submanifolds that intersected at a single point were called "tangent manifolds".  Given you comments, that would seem to be wrong.  I am new to this (as you can surely tell).  I read about transversality, and have seen the term "tangency" used but never defined.  (more...)

@TedShifrin (continued...) What I really want to know is if the circumstance that two (say) 3-d submanifolds of a 4-d space intersect, how do I determine if the result is a new 3-d submanifold which is comprised of the two intersecting submanifolds, or whether the intersection does not results in a merging (bad word) of the two submanifolds because of the way they intersect (non-transversely).

Whether two submanifolds intersect transversely or tangentially, with a non-empty intersection the union is never a manifold. Try working the example I gave you two comments up.

@TedShifrin Oh, ok.  Thanks.  I guess I have some learning to do... So if I have two 2-d planes of the same size (say of finite length and width), and I arrange them end-to-end so that they are in contact (with no gap), the results isn't a single, larger, 2-d plane?

Nope. You’re talking about gluing manifolds with boundary that intersect tangentially along their boundaries. That is a different situation. Yes, there is plenty of learning to do. Start with some good books.

@TedShifrin As a pedantic aside, you could avoid the boundary issue there by considering two open half planes instead, say the upper half of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the lower half shifted up by $1$ so they overlap. The union is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Do we need to assume the intersection has positive codimension there?

Yes, of course, I made the mistake of not assuming the two manifolds overlapped tangentially along a subset of maximal dimension. Perhaps the OP's definition of "tangent manifolds" is that two manifolds overlap tangentially along a subset open in each of them?

I would love to be able to say that's exactly what I meant, but the truth is I don't have enough knowledge to claim that.  It does, however, sound like what I was getting at. I hesitate to use this platform to teach me what I need to know, so before I start asking questions without having at least a base-level of knowledge, can anyone recommend a good, introductory, text?  I have a good level of maths and science, but have never studied this field (so I don't understand all the nomenclature and even some of the basic concepts).
